# How do I change the delimiter from a text file?

Tags: java, delimiter

Let's say I got a *textfile.txt* that I want to read from. This is the text in the file:

```
23:years:old
15:years:young
```

Using the `useDelimiter` method, how can I tell my program that `:` and newlines are delimiters? Putting the text in one line and using `useDelimter(":");` works. The problem is when I got several lines of text.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt));
input.useDelimiter(:);

while(data.hasNextLine()) {
 int age = input.nextInt();
 String something = input.next();
 String somethingelse = input.next();
}
```

Using this code I will get an inputMisMatch error.

Comment: can you paste your code if you have tried? because its simple and you can place check that if this is the last token of this line then again use delimiter

Comment: I am unable to understand What is this "data"? Here this line while(data.hasNextLine()) must be like while(input.hasNextLine())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
            Scanner input;
        String tokenizer[]; 
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("D:\\textfile.txt"));
            input.useDelimiter("\\n");
                while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                    tokenizer = input.next().split(":"); 
                     System.out.println(tokenizer[0]+"   |"+tokenizer[1]+" | "+tokenizer[2]);

                    }


        }catch(Exception e){}
```

It will give you output like

```
23 |years | old

15 |years | young
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[:]+");
```

The complete code is

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/temp/text.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter("[:]+");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

The output is

```
23
years
old
15
years
young
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want the output to be:

23 years old
15 years young

What should I use then?

Comment: Then you can process the string line by line and delimit the line string by ":".

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this:

1. Concatenate the string to make it one line.
2. delimit "newline" first, then delimit ":" each return string token.

Comment: How do I delimit a newline? useDelimit("\n"); ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get everything split up all at once then I guess you can use

```
useDelimiter(":\\n")
```

That should split on both : and newspace but it is not the most efficient way of processing data, especially if each line of text is set out in the same format and represents a complete entry. If that is the case then my suggestion would be to only split on a new line to begin with, like this;

```
s.useDelimiter("\\n");
while(s.hasNext()){
    String[] result = s.next.split(":");
    //do whatever you need to with the data and store it somewhere
}
```

This will allow you to process the data line by line and will also split it at the required places. However if you do plan on going through line by line I recommend you look at BufferedReader as it has a readLine() function that makes things a lot easier.

Comment: oops, it should be useDelimiter(":|\\n")

Answer (score 0):

you probably wants to create a delimiter pattern which includes both ':' and newline
I didn't test it, but [\s|:]+ is a regular expression that matches one or more whitespace characters, and also ':'.
Try put:

```
input.useDelimiter("[\\s|:]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the lines have all three fields you can just use `input.useDelimiter(":\n");`